# Word report automation sourcing numbers from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to automate reporting in word by extracting numbers from Excel. I searched and followed the code sourced from  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/

Code doesn't run properly and encounters a number of errors.
1. Excel doesn't open
2. Encounter Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

I have used the "early binding" code suggested by website and doesn't work and the researched to use "late binding". still doesn't work. I inserted "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" and insert "Label" in word doc under "ActiveX  Control"

Don't know what went wrong.

**Current vba code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\adong\Desktop\Reporting.xlsx")

ThisDocument.DMY.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Summary").Cell(5, 4)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Previous code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\adong\Desktop\Reporting.xlsx")

ThisDocument.DMY.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, 4)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You will not see Excel open unless you add `objExcel.Visisble = True` after creating the Excel instance.  Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Thanks Tim. You can my level of skills now.

Comment: It is this line it showed run-time error

Comment: ThisDocument.DMY.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, 4)

Comment: does substituting `thisdocument.DMY.caption = "Hello"` still get the err 438?

Comment: See the accepted answer here for how to refer to ActiveX controls hosted in a Word document: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26874253/How-to-loop-with-VBA-on-all-controls-placed-in-a-Word-doc.html

Comment: Winterknell, tried the code suggested and it works fine showing the word "Hello".                                                                                            How can I make it work with referring to numbers in excel?     Also How do I replace the Cell (5,4) with a named range reference? thanks

Comment: when replaced with "Hello" with exWb.Shees("Summary").Cell(8,3) it comes back with Run-tim error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: also tried using Text box instead of Label; execute this line ThisDocument.DMY.Text = exWb.Sheets("Summary").Cell(5, 4); the same run-time error message

Answer (score 0):

Adapting code from: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26874253/How-to-loop-with-VBA-on-all-controls-placed-in-a-Word-doc.html

You can write a utility function to get an ActiveX control given its name and the hosting document:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim con As Object
    Dim objExcel As Object, exWb As Object


    Set con = ActiveXControlByName(ThisDocument, "DMY")
    If Not con Is Nothing Then

        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\adong\Desktop\Reporting.xlsx")
        con.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Summary").Cell(5, 4).Value
        exWb.Close False
        Set exWb = Nothing
        objExcel.Quit

     End If

End Sub

Function ActiveXControlByName(doc As Document, theName As String) As Object
    Dim ilsh As InlineShape
    Dim sh As Shape, ob As Object
    For Each ilsh In doc.InlineShapes
        If ilsh.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
            Set ob = ilsh.OLEFormat.Object
            If ob.Name = theName Then
                Set ActiveXControlByName = ob
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next ilsh
    For Each sh In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            Set ob = sh.OLEFormat.Object
            If ob.Name = theName Then
                Set ActiveXControlByName = ob
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    'if got here then control was not found...
    Set ActiveXControlByName = Nothing
End Function
```